# Unable to launch Multiple Project in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am not quite sure what is the problem with the following error. It works couple of time and then start getting this issue:[image]

I am able to launch single project but having issue with multiple startup project. This really bugging me a lot. When you start your API service and then Front-end but sometimes API itself shutdown before i could start my app to run, and then what, you will start all over again. Start your API and then Front-end project. It may be fine for some folks but my machine itself started to cry like hell and had to wait almost 1-2 minutes to actually working again, which is really a painful process and over the top VS consuming my 100% disk usage.

Any thoughts!!

Comment: When you open Visual Studio as Administrator, are you getting the same error message?

Comment: I have just tried to check in admin mode and it seems working as of now but i am not quite sure about it as it has happened before as well. It works couple of times and then boom!!! Let's see how this turns out to be. BTW thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've read that sometimes the vssettings file gets corrupted, or have inside some wrong data, and then it generates this kind of message.

If it's the case, all should be solved by deleting CurrentSettings.vssettings

This file is located at Tools > Options > Environment > Import and Export Settings.

You can find it at: Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Settings

Maybe this helps you.